# Something like foreach in htaccesss?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, url, rewritecond

I am in this situation:

```
url: domain/var1/var2/var3/.../varn
```

And I want to change that url in:

```
url: domain?v1=var1&v2=var2&v3=var3/.../&vn=varn
```

I found this way:

```
RewriteRule domain/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ domain/index.php?v1=$1&v2=$2 [QSA,NC]
```

But as you can see I have to specify all the vars manually... 
Is there a way to do it automatically?
Something like: while there is a   `/([^/]+)` add `v{N}=${N}` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do a while loop, but AFAIK rewrite engine does not provide a loop counter.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?domain/([^/]+)/?([^?]+)/?$ /domain/$2/?piece[]=$1 [QSA,N=50]
RewriteRule . domain/index.php [L,NS]
```

`php` will parse into the array `_GET['piece']`.

*I'm really curious why you're not using `php` to parse the url.*

Comment: What would you do? (I read about the "tecnic" of put the request url in a GET var and parse that with php)